# How to use string inside a javascript selector inside a looping?

Tags: javascript

I have form like this:

```
<form id="stuff">
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey1" id="roundkey1" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R2 : ROund key 2 <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey2" id="roundkey2" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R3 : ROund key 3 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey3" id="roundkey3" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R4 : ROund key 4 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey4" id="roundkey4" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R5 : ROund key 5 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey5" id="roundkey5" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R6 : ROund key 6 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey6" id="roundkey6" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R7 : ROund key 7 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey7" id="roundkey7" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R8 : ROund key 8 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey8" id="roundkey8" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R9 : ROund key 9 // *EUROBEAT INTENSIEF Stop<BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey9" id="roundkey9" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
</form>
```

I have to select each textarea so i can insert a string which is inside `accumulated_output_info` variable;

i need to foreach that when i click a button using a loop like below:

```
for(var round = 1; round < 10;round++){
 document.stuff.roundkey+round.value = accumulated_output_info;
}
```

but i got an error like this:

> (index):732 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in
>   assignment

what could go wrong with my code ? how do i suppose to write that kind of string ?

Comment: `document.stuff.roundkey+round.value` is invalid, you can't do that before an assignment statement

Comment: so how do i suppose to write ? @SterlingArcher

Comment: What do you mean by "selector"? What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Try line by line. First do that `=` operation to `round.value`, then assign that what you have got to `document.stuff.roundkey`. `round` is a primitive and you are turning that into an object with `.value`. You will get `undefined`

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: wait let me fix that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @SterlingArcher i have edited my question, please check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying use the property dynamically, use the square bracket notation, instead of `.` notation

```
document.forms.stuff['roundkey'+round].value = "Hello "+ round;
```

---

Edit :

```js
for(var round = 1; round < 10;round++){
 debugger;
 document.forms.stuff['roundkey'+round].value = "Hello "+ round;

}
```

```html
<form id="stuff">
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey1" id="roundkey1" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R2 : ROund key 2 <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey2" id="roundkey2" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R3 : ROund key 3 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey3" id="roundkey3" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R4 : ROund key 4 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey4" id="roundkey4" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R5 : ROund key 5 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey5" id="roundkey5" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R6 : ROund key 6 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey6" id="roundkey6" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R7 : ROund key 7 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey7" id="roundkey7" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R8 : ROund key 8 // <BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey8" id="roundkey8" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
Details R9 : ROund key 9 // *EUROBEAT INTENSIEF Stop<BR>
<TEXTAREA name="roundkey9" id="roundkey9" rows="10" cols="40"></TEXTAREA>
</form>
```